# How to use the identity() inside the Convert() in MS SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I'm using MS SQL. I want to use the `identity()` inside the `convert()` to generate something like this:

> 2016071000
>
> 2016071001

I have written a query as follows:

```
SELECT  convert(varchar,datepart(yyyy,getdate()))+
        substring(CONVERT(varchar,getdate(),112),5,2)+
        CONVERT(varchar,identity(1000,1));
```

But I'm getting the error as

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'identity'.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use table with numbers you need:

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT  1000 as id,
        1 as lev
UNION ALL
SELECT  id+1,
        lev+1
FROM cte
WHERE lev < 100
)

SELECT convert(varchar,datepart(yyyy,getdate()))+substring(CONVERT(varchar,getdate(),112),5,2)+CONVERT(varchar,id)
FROM cte
```

This will produce 100 rows like:

```
2016071000
2016071001
2016071002
...
2016071099
```

Another way is to use sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.TestSequence  
    START WITH 1000 
    INCREMENT BY 1 ;
```

Then run:

```
SELECT convert(varchar,datepart(yyyy,getdate()))+substring(CONVERT(varchar,getdate(),112),5,2)+ CAST(NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.TestSequence as nvarchar(10))
```

Output:

```
2016071000
```

Next run will be `2016071001` and so on.

If you need to restart sequence use:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE dbo.TestSequence  
    RESTART WITH 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can with `ROW_NUMBER`

```
SELECT  
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(yyyy,GETDATE())) +
    SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(), 112), 5, 2) +
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) + 999)
FROM
    Tbl
```